# Velocity and acceleration problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1. Show that if the dot product of the velocity and acceleration of a moving particle is positive (or negative), then the speed of the particle is increasing (or decreasing).
2. If at all times t the position and velocity vectors of a moving particle satisfy $v(t)=r(t)$, and if $r(0)=r_0$, find $r(t)$ and the acceleration $a(t)$. What is the path of the motion?

Please help!

1. Solution proposal

$u(t)^2$= **v * v**

I then differentiate both sides and get

$2u du/dt$=**av**+**va**=2**va**

$u du/dt$=**va**

Which IMO shows that when the dot product is positive so is the speed

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Though this problem is relatively trivial - if you want us to help you with your homework, you're going to have to put in some effort yourself.)

Comment: The first one I think I have solved but I am not sure if it is correct. The second I have got stuck when I integrate.

Comment: For 1,think it in Physics. For 2 , it is ODE.

Comment: For 2, it's one dimensional motion.

Comment: For 2 I have the general solution $y=y_0e^(2t)$. How do I find the constant $y_0$?

Comment: @Nash , for precisely , $r(t)=y_0 e^{t}$ with $r(0)=y_0=r_0$

Comment: Ah thanks! @Syuizen

Comment: Can one draw conclusions for the path of the motion?

Answer (score 1):

for the first one notice that:
$${\bf v}. {\bf a}={\bf v}.{d{\bf v}\over dt}={d\over dt}({1\over 2}{\bf v}. {\bf v})={d\over dt}({1\over 2}\|v\|^2)$$
for the second:
$${d{\bf r}\over dt}={\bf r} \quad \Rightarrow \quad {\bf r}(t)={\bf r}(0)\, e^t={\bf r}_0\, e^t \\ \Rightarrow {\bf v}(t)={\bf a}(t)={\bf r}_0\, e^t$$
It is easy to see the path of the motion is a semi-line contains $\bf r_0$.